# I find a serious bug with android google-vr-cardboard and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I find a serious Android bug, and can't solve it.

The bug is:

Use unity3D export android project now I have unityvractivity.jar, and use Google VR Cardboard ,I have commonwidget.aar 。Then unityvractivity.jar and commonwidget.aar also have the "com.google.vr.cardboard.UiLayer"  。 So When I use Google VR Cardboard It Use  UiLayer in unityvractivity.jar 。 So crash!

I can't unzip commonwidget.aar， so can't solve it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this problem is google-vr-android and google-vr-unity crash .

Comment: Google cardboard SDK is maintained by google if you think you've found a bug you should report it on their issue tracker https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk